# Populating and printing the elements of a personal LinkedList reproduction

Tags: java, list, abstract-class

this will be a little difficult to illustrate since the code is separated between several classes but I can't figure it out myself.

This code is supposed to first print "This list is empty." and then print each word within stringData in a single line:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList_1 list1 = new LinkedList_1(null);
        list1.printList(list1.getRoot());

        String stringData = "Harrier Ken Klaasje Titus Evrart Manaaba Cindy Eyckhead";
        String[] data = stringData.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < (data.length); i++) {
            list1.addItem(new Node(data[i]));
        }
        list1.printList(list1.getRoot());
    }
}
```

The code prints "This list is empty." once and then seemingly never reaches the second print out line but there is no exception, notification, anything. I suspect that the problem hides in list1.addItem, which looks like this(the comments were only meant for myself):

```
        @Override
    public boolean addItem(ListItem newItem)
    {
        if (this.root == null) { // If no other item on list, newItem = first item on list
            this.root = newItem;
            return true;
        }
        ListItem current = this.root; // current = first item on list
        while (current != null) { // As long as current exists, do
            int comparison = (current.CompareTo(newItem)); // Alphabetically compares newItem and current. >0 = newItem comes AFTER current. <0 = newItem comes BEFORE current. 0 = newItem and current are identical.
            // ........................................................................................................
            if (comparison < 0) { // newItem should be inserted AFTER current
                if (current.getNext() != null) { // If the list contains another item after current, then
                    current = current.getNext(); // current becomes next item in list.
                    // outcome AFTER-NOT LAST YET is completed and the while loop will repeat until newItem is either last or no longer comes after
                } else { // if current is only item on list, then
                    current.setNextItem(newItem); // newItem comes after current
                    newItem.setPreviousItem(current); // current comes before after
                    return true; // outcome AFTER-LAST completed ---> drop out of the method/loop
                } // ........................................................................................................
            } else if (comparison > 0) { // newItem comes BEFORE current
                if (current.getPrevious() != null) { // if current is not first in list, then
                    current.getPrevious().setNextItem(newItem); // newItem comes after item that comes before new item (1. previous 2. newItem)
                    newItem.setPreviousItem(current.getPrevious()); // previous comes before newItem
                    newItem.setNextItem(current); // current comes after newItem (1.previous 2. newItem 3. current)
                    current.setPreviousItem(newItem); // newItem comes before current
                    // outcome BEFORE-NOT FIRST YET is completed and the while loop will repeat until newItem is either first or no longer comes before
                } else { // if current is first in list
                    newItem.setNextItem(this.root); // newItem comes before root (=current)
                    this.root.setPreviousItem(newItem); // root (=current) comes after newItem
                    this.root = newItem; // newItem is now root
                    return true;  // outcome BEFORE-FIRST completed ---> drop out of the method/loop
                }// ........................................................................................................
            } else { // curent == newItem. As a duplicate, newItem is not added to the list
                System.out.println(newItem.getValue() + " is already part of the List.class Duplicate not added.");
                return false; // drop out of the method/loop without adding newItem to the list
        }   }
        return false; // drop out of the loop without adding newItem to the list (how you would ever get here I don't know
    }
```

Now maybe someone can already spot a problem or maybe its located in one of the other classes. Since I don't want to paste the whole code (although it's a rather short training program) into a new thread, maybe you could tell me which information is missing to understand the issue and I add or remove specific pieces?

In any case, thanks in advance for your help.

On second thought, let me add what .printList does right away.

```
    public void printList(ListItem root)
    {
        if (root == null) {
            System.out.println("This list is empty.");
        } else {
            while (root != null) {
                System.out.println(root.getValue());
                root = root.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
```

ListItem class:

```
public abstract class ListItem
{
    protected ListItem previousItem = null;
    protected ListItem nextItem = null;
    protected Object value;

    public ListItem(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    abstract ListItem getNext();
    abstract ListItem getPrevious();
    abstract void setNextItem(ListItem n);
    abstract void setPreviousItem(ListItem p);
    abstract int CompareTo(ListItem item);
}
```

Node class:

```
public class Node extends ListItem
{

    public Node(Object value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    ListItem getNext() {
        return this.nextItem;
    }
    @Override
    ListItem getPrevious() {
        return this.previousItem;
    }
    @Override
    void setNextItem(ListItem n) {
        this.nextItem = n;
    }
    @Override
    void setPreviousItem(ListItem p) {
        this.previousItem = p;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    int CompareTo(ListItem item)
    {
        if (item != null) {
            return ((String)super.getValue()).compareTo((String)item.getValue());
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are `Node` and `ListItem` related?

Comment: @RandyCasburn `data` comes from String.split, not the list.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException - well wasn't my comment "Dodgy" - :-)

Comment: Right as Dodgy pointed out. Thanks.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException ```Node``` extents the abstract class ```ListItem```.

Comment: What is list ListItem?

Comment: Is Node(String data) properly initialising previous and next references? addItem might end up in infinite loop if they are not initialised to null.

Comment: @rishavprasher I added ListItem and Node to the original post.

Comment: @MohdWaseem That might be the reason. previousItem and nextItem are initialized in the super class but not explicitly in the Node class. I added both to the original post. Maybe you could take another look?

Comment: can try changing the parameter type of additem method and printlist method to Node object instead of ListItem object as Listitem is abstract class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return in one case which is why it is going in infinite loop.

```
    if (comparison > 0) { // newItem comes BEFORE current
                if (current.getPrevious() != null) { 
                    current.getPrevious().setNextItem(newItem); 
                    newItem.setPreviousItem(current.getPrevious()); 
                    newItem.setNextItem(current); 
                    current.setPreviousItem(newItem); 
                    // return when element is added successfully
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I first needed to check if newItem might not also come before what's now its previous item.```else if (comparison > 0) {
    if (current.getPrevious() != null) {
     current.getPrevious().setNextItem(newItem);
     newItem.setPreviousItem(current.getPrevious());
     newItem.setNextItem(current);
     current.setPreviousItem(newItem);
     current = newItem.getPrevious();
     int comparison2 = (current.CompareTo(newItem));
     if (comparison2 < 0) {
      return true;
     }```

Comment: why do you want to do that? you already compared current.getPrevious() with newItem in the previous iteration.`if (comparison2 < 0)` will always be true. wouldn't it?

Comment: Oh, you're right, since every new item is compared against the left most item first. For a moment I thought a new item might be compared against other items from right to left.